# How to move element's x/y position with js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]
I have added a picture to describe what I need. here I have a container with yellow border and content with a red border, I want it to scroll to left for 1 container's width when I click the button in the container.

I have tried the CSS animation but it seems not what I want. so it's there a way to achieve what I want?

I have write a demo here :
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-panini-hel36

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I have a demo here :https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-panini-hel36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by adding a class to the div you'll want to move (moveDiv) and style it with `position:relative`.

Then, add a class to the button you want to click to trigger the action (actionButton).

Afterwards, place the following JavaScript in the end of the page in between  tags

```
document.getElementsByClassName("actionButton").addEventListener('mousedown',function(){
    var left = document.getElementsByClassName("moveDiv")[0].style.left;
    left = left === '150px' ? 0 : '150px';
    document.getElementsByClassName("moveDiv")[0].style.left = left;
});
```

This has an event listener knowing when the mouse is down (when user clicks the button). Change the left position accordingly to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the anwser, it works, but can it have a animation ?

Comment: Sure. To use CSS animation, you must first specify some keyframes for the animation; they will hold what styles the element will have at certain times. To add animation you need to add `document.getElementsByClassName("moveDiv")[0].style.animation = "mynewmove 4s 2";`  and create keyframes. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_animation) an example.

Comment: thank for your answer, I found a easy way to do it , to use scrollTo(x,y,smooh) , but not to scroll the content div, move the container instead.